# Using restful path helper methods in a separate lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, helper

In a certain module that I am using in my application, I would like to use the method alarm_path(alarm). How can I include this method in my current module?

I already tried to include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper, though, it still complain that this method does not exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add this instead of your current `include`:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```